# how to add add list element names as a variable in the output

Tags: r

I have a list of data.frames looks like this:

```
$IB1Q
         V1          V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7          V8 
0.184011746 0.805070251 0.840738769 0.701748191 0.493042421 0.889981450 0.003934755 0.794561335 
         V9         V10         V11 
0.664718057 0.880357401 0.545795252 

$IBCA
       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6        V7        V8        V9 
0.8719393 0.8177656 0.9205127 0.7200678 0.7456413 0.4643883 0.8006192 0.1430972 0.7622733 
      V10       V11 
0.4716331 0.8681162
```

and each element name (IB1Q, IBCA) conveys information. I want to row.bind them together and in my data.farme I want a 
variable for the list elemnt each observation originated in.
So I want to get a data.frame with 2 columns (first column popID and second columns my proportions):

```
IB1Q   0.184011746
IB1Q   0.805070251
IB1Q   0.840738769
IB1Q   0.701748191
IB1Q   0.493042421
.
.
.
IBCA   0.4716331
IBCA   0.8681162
```

Comment: Data frames have only one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one thought:

```
mylist <- list(
  IB1Q = as.data.frame(setNames(
    list(0.184011746, 0.805070251, 0.840738769, 0.701748191, 0.493042421, 0.889981450, 0.003934755, 0.794561335, 0.664718057, 0.880357401, 0.545795252),
    paste0("V", 1:11)
  )),
  IBCA = as.data.frame(setNames(
    list(0.8719393, 0.8177656, 0.9205127, 0.7200678, 0.7456413, 0.4643883, 0.8006192, 0.1430972, 0.7622733, 0.4716331, 0.8681162),
    paste0("V", 1:11)
  ))
)

do.call(rbind.data.frame,
        lapply(names(mylist), function(n) data.frame(K=n, V=unlist(mylist[[n]], use.names = FALSE)))
        )
#       K           V
# 1  IB1Q 0.184011746
# 2  IB1Q 0.805070251
# 3  IB1Q 0.840738769
# 4  IB1Q 0.701748191
# 5  IB1Q 0.493042421
# 6  IB1Q 0.889981450
# 7  IB1Q 0.003934755
# 8  IB1Q 0.794561335
# 9  IB1Q 0.664718057
# 10 IB1Q 0.880357401
# 11 IB1Q 0.545795252
# 12 IBCA 0.871939300
# 13 IBCA 0.817765600
# 14 IBCA 0.920512700
# 15 IBCA 0.720067800
# 16 IBCA 0.745641300
# 17 IBCA 0.464388300
# 18 IBCA 0.800619200
# 19 IBCA 0.143097200
# 20 IBCA 0.762273300
# 21 IBCA 0.471633100
# 22 IBCA 0.868116200
```

Since we're discarding the column names of the nested `data.frame`s, I don't think the use of `unlist` is too harsh/lossy. (I use `use.names=FALSE` because I find row names to be unreliable in the long run ... feel free to keep them if you'd like.)

Comment: I cannot do something like that, my list has more than 50 elements. For each element doing something like mylist <- list(
  IB1Q = as.data.frame(setNames(
    list(0.184011746, 0.805070251, 0.840738769, 0.701748191, 0.493042421, 0.889981450, 0.003934755, 0.794561335, 0.664718057, 0.880357401, 0.545795252),
    paste0("V", 1:11) is very time consumening

Comment: But you don't need to do that ... since you did not provide data in a readily-reproducible form, that code is just to create a data object for the rest of code. You, the OP, get to skip that part and go to the gusto starting with `do.call(` and replacing `mylist` with whatever the name of your `list` of `data.frame`s is.

Comment: Yesss, thanks so much @r2evans. it did exactly what I wanted. Sorry I did not get your point first.

Comment: (In the future, if you can provide code similar to my declaration of `mylist` within your question, it will make answering it faster and less likely to fall apart due to faulty assumptions. Better yet, if there is any doubt, provide similar code for desired output ... though there was no doubt in this instance.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loops here.  You can use `rep()` and `unlist()`.

```
data.frame(
    popID = rep(names(mylist), lengths(mylist)),
    prop = unlist(mylist, use.names=FALSE) # use.names=FALSE for speed
)
```

`lengths()` is useful here because it gives us the number of columns per list element.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. Very concise and clear (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way it could be done (using `mylist` provided in @r2evans answer):

```r
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(mylist, .id = "popID") %>% 
  gather(key, value, -popID) %>% select(-key) %>% arrange(popID)
#>    popID       value
#> 1   IB1Q 0.184011746
#> 2   IB1Q 0.805070251
#> 3   IB1Q 0.840738769
#> 4   IB1Q 0.701748191
#> 5   IB1Q 0.493042421
#> 6   IB1Q 0.889981450
#> 7   IB1Q 0.003934755
#> 8   IB1Q 0.794561335
#> 9   IB1Q 0.664718057
#> 10  IB1Q 0.880357401
#> 11  IB1Q 0.545795252
#> 12  IBCA 0.871939300
#> 13  IBCA 0.817765600
#> 14  IBCA 0.920512700
#> 15  IBCA 0.720067800
#> 16  IBCA 0.745641300
#> 17  IBCA 0.464388300
#> 18  IBCA 0.800619200
#> 19  IBCA 0.143097200
#> 20  IBCA 0.762273300
#> 21  IBCA 0.471633100
#> 22  IBCA 0.868116200
```